# random forest classifier- rocplot gives a diagonal line

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, roc

I am working with a small dataset (57 rows), and i am trying to make a prediction on disease activity i.e. active vs healthy. When I want to asses the performance of my classifier by looking at the rocplot i get a rocplot with a diagonal line:
[image: RF rocplot]

the corresponding confusion matrix:[image: confusion matrix of RF classifier]

I am trying to understand why the rocplot is showing a diagonal line while the confusion matrix is showing that 5 samples are missclassified.What am i missing? I also tried this dataset on a svm-classifier and the rocplot and confusion matrix are:

[image: Rocplot SVM classifier]
[[image: Confusion matrix svm classifier4]

I know that SVM is overfitting but the way the rocplot is built makes somewhat more sense to me

the settings that I have been using for RF:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(
    verbose=0,
    criterion='gini',
    max_depth=150,
    max_features='auto',
    max_leaf_nodes=None,
    max_samples=None,
    min_samples_leaf=20,
    min_samples_split=10,
    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
    n_estimators=200,
    n_jobs=-1,
    oob_score=False,
    random_state=42,
    min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
    min_impurity_split=None,
    bootstrap=True,
    warm_start=False
)
```

the code I use to fit the model:

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

the code for plotting a rocplot:

```
clf_disp = plot_roc_curve(clf, X_test,y_test.values.ravel())
plt.show()
```

updated rocplot after adjusting min_samples_split and

[image: Rocplot RF after adjusting min_samples_leafmin_samples_split]

updated parameter settings:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(
    verbose=0,
    criterion='gini',
    max_depth=10,
    max_features='auto',
    max_leaf_nodes=None,
    max_samples=None,
    min_samples_leaf=9,
    min_samples_split=20,
    min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0,
    n_estimators=180,
    n_jobs=-1,
    oob_score=True,
    random_state=42,
    min_impurity_decrease=0.0,
    min_impurity_split=None,
    bootstrap=True,
   
)
```

Comment: Can you show the code used to plot the ROC curve? Additionally, when you have so few items (57) but increase `min_samples_leaf`=20, it's only possible for each tree to make 1 or 2 splits at the most before hitting that limit. Possibly that's a reason it's not fitting as well as you want?

Comment: Just added the code for the plotting

Comment: Try changing `min_samples_leaf` and `min_samples_split` to be something like 1% of your training data rows. Because these values are set so high, the trees aren't allowed to do enough splits, so it's probably classifying all 12 test examples as 100% probability to be in one class or another and therefore the AUC will be around 0.5 always.

Comment: I did as what you suggested, and i see an improvement in the rocplot(auc of 0.79)..however the confusion matrix stays the same i..e the samples still get classified in one group. This does not make entirely sense, shouldn't the confusion matrix improve if the rocplot improves, since both are based on the test set? I added the results to my first comments. Also, I understand that this model might be overfitting(the chosen split gave me the highest AUC). but somehow i did expect the confusion matrix to change in its results